# Is there a way to show multiple displays on same page (different parts of page) with vuetify or plain vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Just want to know if it is possible to show different pages on a single page. Maybe like in a form of a split pane.
For example, I want to have a page that has four equal spaces (like a box split in four) and I want to dynamically change the contents of each of these boxes based on events that occur in the other boxes (just a rough picture).
Would this be possible? And how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean, like different routes in a single page?

Comment: @JenuelGanawed. Yes. I want to change what the pages mounted on these routes dynamically. Right now, you have to define what pages are mounted on these routes manually in router.js but I want to alter the configuration from code lets say when a button is clicked on a different page within the same parent route.

Answer (score 0):

Vuetify includes a [grid system](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/) that provides `row` and `column` elements to achieve most any layout. Please take a look at the many examples on the [docs page](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/) for guidance on how to construct, for example, a layout with 2 rows and 2 columns.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @NoahStahl. Although what I really want to do is change the occupants of different router-view portals dynamically with for example a button click on another router-view occupying component.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is dynamically adding components, you can use Vue's [`<component/>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html). The usage is something like this:

```html
<component :is="MyComponent"/>
```

```js
import MyComponent from "@/components/MyComponent";

export default {
  ...
}
```

Here is a sample [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-hooks-nsjem?file=/src/components/Playground.vue).

[image]

Comment: Hi @Blackraspberryyy. Thanks a bunch for this! I suppose one way I can achieve what I want is by using this method and changing the elements within the page array in the data object rather than depending on router-view to be able to change it dynamically. It does make sense now. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do flex, and if you want to use routings then you can actually configure your router file.

> sample code here https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-hermann-sui9z

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="boxes">
      <div class="pages p1">
        <router-view name="p1"></router-view>
      </div>
      <div class="pages p2">
        <router-view name="p2"></router-view>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxes">
      <div class="pages p3">
        <router-view name="p3"></router-view>
      </div>
      <div class="pages p4">
        <router-view name="p4"></router-view>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thanks, @JenuelGanawed Yes exactly. But now, the trick I want to perform is to change let's say page 2 to page 10 when I click a button on page 3 - all dynamically, not by manual definition in router.js